# What is the meaning of "Voilà, monsieur, qu'il dit cet homme." by Queneau?

Tags: que

> Voilà, monsieur, qu'il dit cet homme.
> (*Le Cheval Troyen*, 1948)

'There you are, sir, said this man.' But why the 'qu'il'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a colloquial *incise*<sup>1</sup>. The regular one would have been *dit-il* or *dit cet homme*. French normally demand subject-verb inversion in these clauses.

The phrase avoids the inversion and the subject redundancy emphasizes *cet homme*. This kind of expression is often done to criticize or make fun about what has been said.

Note also that the *L* in *qu'i**l** dit* is usually dropped along with some or all of its *e muets* so this expression might be written :

> Voilà, m'sieur, qu'y dit c't'homme.

Here is a running gag from [Astérix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix):

[image]

Here, that will be pronounced: /...ki disɛ/

As Eau qui dort commented, studies show that this kind of *incise* is more common without *que* in spontaneous spoken French, perhaps because it is perceived to be less "incorrect".

---

Reference:

> La langue populaire, qui répugne à l'inversion, laisse souvent le pronom devant le verbe de l'incise, mais en introduisant celle-ci par *que* : voir notamment Bauche, p. 134. C'est l'usage parlé que reproduisent les exemples suivants :
> *Pauvre bête, **QUE** je lui dis, si on doit tuer tout ce qui est vilain, je n'aurais pas plus que toi le droit de vivre* (George Sand, La Petite Fadette)
> Grevisse et Goosse, *Le Bon Usage, 14<sup>e</sup> édition*, § 380, p. 473, 2008

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>[Reporting clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/reported-speech-direct-speech)</sub>

Comment: Ha! Today I learned. Funny enough, this has the same effect in English when one postposes the attribution. "Join the army!" they said. "See the world!" they said. The ironic tone might also depend on the unique intonation, though.

Comment: I don't see any inversion. What I see is a colloquial use of the relative pronoun.

Comment: @Lambie You do not see an inversion precisely because there is no inversion. *Incises* normally demand inversion.

Comment: I don't think this is "une incise", really. That means a parenthetical comment or phrase. I think it's a **usage populaire** of the relative pronoun. And you say: "The phrase avoids the inversion". What inversion? There is no need for one at all. As you yourself point out, it could be: dit cet homme.

Comment: @Lambie It is definitely an incise and what is *dit cet homme* if not an inversion??

Comment: @Lambie Extrait du Bon usage, 14e édition : *La langue populaire, qui répugne à l'inversion, laisse souvent le pronom devant le verbe de **l'incise**, mais en introduisant celle-ci par que : voir notamment Bauche, p. 134 . C'est l'usage parlé que reproduisent les ex. suivants :
Pauvre bête, QUE je lui dis, si on doit tuer tout ce qui est vilain, je n'aurais pas
plus que toi le droit de vivre (SAND, Pet. Fadette, XVIII).*

Comment: I think this study: https://www.persee.fr/doc/linx_0246-8743_1989_num_20_1_1121 covers the most of the non-standard uses for the relative pronouns. The point is the "misuse" of the relative clause.  Compare the standard usage: Voilà, Monsieur, **c'est ce qu'il dit cet homme**. The inversion is not the main point here.

Comment: The document you cite doesn't cover the *que* usage of the OP question. If you think otherwise, feel free to write you own answer.

Comment: @None Not arguing your main point at all, but there's something I want to stress for any learner reading this: "Que" isn't needed to avoid the inversion, it's perfectly normal to produce sentences like "Sortez, je lui ai dit à ce type, si vous savez pas vous tenir". Corpus studies have shown they're more frequent than the structure with "que" in spontaneous speech. But the "que" variant has been stereotyped to the point of being almost obligatory in literary reproduction of colloquial speech.

Comment: @Eauquidort Sans remettre en cause ces études, dont j'ai repris la conclusion dans ma réponse, j'ai quand même l'impression que /kidi/ est plus courant que /idi/ au moins quand il s'agit de se moquer, de ridiculiser ce qu'a dit quelqu'un, par exemple : *Il est plus fort que moi, **qu'il dit***.

Comment: It seems to me that the addition of "que" is like adding in English "is what"; for example, '"There you go, sir", is what he said'.

Comment: @HarryAudus Would it be colloquial and carrying a mocking tone in English?

Comment: @jilliagre. No, merely emphatic.

Comment: @HarryAudus then they don't match. *Qu'il dit cet homme* is very different from *Est ce que dit cet homme*.

Comment: @jilliagre. Ok. Thanks for the clarification.